# Mount Amazon EFS from different VPC through VPC Peering

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc, amazon-efs

I'm searching for a way to synchronize EFS contents over two different EBS cluster. The plan is to mount both EFS into a EC2 instance during deployment to rsync the contents afterwards.

Our Setup:

- 2 ELB Cluster
- each in an own VPC with 3 availability zones
- one is our stage/maintenance cluster, where our customer uploads media data and creates CMS-pages etc. and one for production purpose
- each of the ELB's uses an EFS to store User generated content, such uploaded images etc.

The goal:

- synchronize EFS1 to EFS2 during deployments
- therefore both EFS should be mounted in one of the LIVE clusters EC2 instances
- this way the contents could be synchronized from one mountpoint to the other one using rsync

Current status:

- ELB and EFS working great for each of the two domains (stage / live)
  we peeres the VPCs successfully with DNS resolution in both directions
- I added the complete STAGE CIDR as a route to the VPC-Peering for LIVE
- I allowed the access to the STAGE EFS for the live webserver security group in the EFS security group for STAGE EFS.
- I can ping the EC2 instances of the STAGE EBS from a EC2 instance of the LIVE EBS via DNS-name

The problem is I can't mount the STAGE EFS inside of my LIVE EC2s. In contrast to the EC2 DNS names, the hostname cannot be resolved (mount.nfs4: Failed to resolve server eu-west-1b.fs-123456.efs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com: Name or service not known)

What's wrong with my setup/strategy or at least point me to the right direction and tell me if it is solvable this way or not?

Comment: I haven't tried this before, but I'm also interested in whether it can work. What instance types are you using? According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/manage-fs-access-change-vpc.html#manage-fs-access-vpc-peering), VPC peering supports EFS mounts on C5 or M5 instances - but I'm not sure why only these types, and whether this manifests as DNS not resolving.. or just the mount failing; there's a lack of info in that documentation. So maybe... resize your instance and give it a go?

Comment: Also you've mentioned an 'EBS cluster' (Elastic Block Store).. then an 'ELB cluster' (Elastic Load Balancer), and you've tagged elastic-beanstalk. Might be worth clarifying?

Answer (score 3):

efs mount from the same account but different VPC, having VPC peering done, but you can mount by using only the private IP address. not by using dns-name, even if you enable dns resolution over vpc peering also it won't work.

Answer (score -4):

Unfortunately Amazon does not allow you to use EFS instances from another VPC. No way, not with the dns or pointing to the IP. I hope it will help you and in time you can look for an alternative.

Please read: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/limits.html#limits-additional-considerations

Comment: Your own link says

"VPC peering within a single AWS Region when using C5 or M5 instances is supported. However, other VPC private connectivity mechanisms such as a VPN connection, interregion VPC peering, and intraregion VPC peering using other instance types are not supported."

Comment: well, they now support AWS VPN and Inter-Region VPC Peering

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/amazon-efs-now-supports-aws-vpn-and-inter-region-vpc-peering/